# What does python print() function actually do?

Tags: python, unicode, printing, python-2.x

I was looking at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979171/how-can-i-escape-xff-xfe-to-a-readable-string) and started wondering what does the `print` actually do.

I have never found out how to use `string.decode()` and `string.encode()` to get an unicode string "out" in the python interactive shell in the same format as the print does. No matter what I do, I get either

1. UnicodeEncodeError or
2. the escaped string with "\x##" notation...

This is python 2.x, but I'm already trying to mend my ways and actually call `print()` :)

Example:

```
>>> import sys
>>> a = '\xAA\xBB\xCC'
>>> print(a)
ª»Ì
>>> a.encode(sys.stdout.encoding)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in ?
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xaa in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
>>> a.decode(sys.stdout.encoding)
u'\xaa\xbb\xcc'
```

**EDIT**:

Why am I asking this? I am sick and tired of `encode()` errors and realized that since `print` can do it (at least in the interactive shell). I know that the **MUST BE A WAY** to magically do the encoding **PROPERLY**, by digging the info what encoding to use from somewhere...

**ADDITIONAL INFO**:
I'm running Python 2.4.3 (#1, Sep  3 2009, 15:37:12) [GCC 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-46)] on linux2

```
>>> sys.stdin.encoding
'ISO-8859-1'
>>> sys.stdout.encoding
'ISO-8859-1'
```

However, the results are the same with Python 2.6.2 (r262:71600, Sep  8 2009, 13:06:43) on the same linux box.

Comment: Could you give us an example of what you tried, what you wanted/expected to get, and what you got? Would help us help you better.

Comment: Is the question related to Python 2 or 3?

Comment: Since he talks about "print function", it's probably Python 3.

Comment: Oh, actually, `print(a)` does not at all work like what you show here for me... Could you provide the exact version of Python you're using, as well as the values of `sys.stdin.encoding` and `sys.stdout.encoding` in your environment? It may well be that some of the "magic" you're trying to replicate only occurs because of something peculiar to your setup... Sorry for not bringing it up first thing, that should have been the obvious thing to do.

Comment: Ok, I'm starting to think that it actually is my terminal, not python that does the 'magic' e.g. converts the binary data to the non-ascii characters...

Comment: Well, I'd definately say that the nice behaviour of `print` is likely to be a happy coincidence brought about by your input and output encodings. As mentioned above (and in the current version of my answer, the most heavily edited ever), in my utf-8 environment Python 2.6.4 has no clue as to how to make sense of your example.

Comment: @Kimvais: Haven't noticed your comment while writing mine... Apparently we agree on this one now. Too bad, I'd definately love Python to do the black encoding voodoo for me... :-(

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**EDIT:** (Major changes between this edit and the previous one... Note: I'm using Python 2.6.4 on an Ubuntu box.)

Firstly, in my first attempt at an answer, I provided some general information on `print` and `str` which I'm going to leave below for the benefit of anybody having simpler issues with `print` and chancing upon this question. As for a new attempt at dealing with the issue experienced by the OP... Basically, I'm inclined to say that there's no silver bullet here and if `print` somehow manages to make sense of a weird string literal, then that's not reproducible behaviour. I'm led to this conclusion by the following funny interaction with Python in my terminal window:

```
>>> print '\xaa\xbb\xcc'
��
```

Have you tried to input ª»Ì directly from the terminal? At a Linux terminal using utf-8 as the encoding, this is actually read in as six bytes, which can then be made to look like three unicode chars with the help of the `decode` method:

```
>>> 'ª»Ì'
'\xc2\xaa\xc2\xbb\xc3\x8c'
>>> 'ª»Ì'.decode(sys.stdin.encoding)
u'\xaa\xbb\xcc'
```

So, the `'\xaa\xbb\xcc'` literal only makes sense if you decode it *as a latin-1 literal* (well, actually you could use a different encoding which agrees with latin-1 on the relevant characters). As for `print` 'just working' in your case, it certainly doesn't for me -- as mentioned above.

This is explained by the fact that when you use a string literal not prefixed with a `u` -- i.e. `"asdf"` rather than `u"asdf"` -- the resulting string will use some non-unicode encoding. No; as a matter of fact, the string object itself is going to be encoding-unaware, and you're going to have to treat it as if it was encoded with encoding x, for the correct value of x. This basic idea leads me to the following:

```
a = '\xAA\xBB\xCC'
a.decode('latin1')
# result: u'\xAA\xBB\xCC'
print(a.decode('latin1'))
# output: ª»Ì
```

Note the lack of decoding errors and the proper output (which I expect to be stay proper at any other box). Apparently your string literal can be made sense of by Python, but not without some help.

Does this help? (At least in understanding how things work, if not in making the handling of encodings any easier...)

---

Now for some funny bits with some explanatory value (hopefully)! This works fine for me:

```
sys.stdout.write("\xAA\xBB\xCC".decode('latin1').encode(sys.stdout.encoding))
```

Skipping either the decode or the encode part results in a unicode-related exception. Theoretically speaking, this makes sense, as the first decode is needed to decide what characters there are in the given string (the only thing obvious on first sight is what *bytes* there are -- the Python 3 idea of having (unicode) strings for characters and bytes for, well, bytes, suddenly seems superbly reasonable), while the encode is needed so that the output respects the encoding of the output stream. Now this

```
sys.stdout.write("ąöî\n".decode(sys.stdin.encoding).encode(sys.stdout.encoding))
```

also works as expected, but the characters are actually coming from the keyboard and so are actually encoded with the stdin encoding... Also,

```
ord('ą'.decode('utf-8').encode('latin2'))
```

returns the correct 177 (my input encoding is utf-8), but '\xc4\x85'.encode('latin2') makes no sense to Python, as it has no clue as to how to make sense of '\xc4\x85' and figures that trying the 'ascii' code is the best it can do.

---

The original answer:

[The relevant bit](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#print) of Python docs (for version 2.6.4) says that `print(obj)` is meant to print out the string given by `str(obj)`. I suppose you could then wrap it in a call to `unicode` (as in `unicode(str(obj))`) to get a unicode string out -- or you could just use Python 3 and exchange this particular nuisance for a couple of different ones. ;-)

Incidentally, this shows that you can manipulate the result of `print`ing an object just like you can manipulate the result of calling `str` on an object, that is by messing with the `__str__` method. Example:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __str__(self):
        return "I'm a Foo!"

print Foo()
```

As for the actual implementation of `print`, I expect this won't be useful at all, but if you *really* want to know what's going on... It's in the file `Python/bltinmodule.c` in the Python sources (I'm looking at version 2.6.4). Search for a line beginning with `builtin_print`. It's actually entirely straightforward, no magic going on there. :-)

Hopefully this answers your question... But if you do have a more arcane problem which I'm missing entirely, do comment, I'll make a second attempt. Also, I'm assuming we're dealing with Python 2.x; otherwise I guess I wouldn't have a useful comment.

Comment: Unfortunately the builtin_print is not in that file in 2.4 http://svn.python.org/view/python/branches/release24-maint/Python/bltinmodule.c?view=markup

Comment: I guess that's because back then, `print` was still syntax, wheras `builtin_print` is needed to get it to work as a function. Also, when decoding strings coming from stdin, you'll want to use `sys.stdin.encoding` rather than `sys.stdout.encoding` -- though on today's typical box in all probability they're the same.

Comment: Um, I guess I'm only hoping to clarify the goings on under the hood with the last amendment to the answer -- as for what can be done to avoid encoding issues, I guess it's not very optimistic. Anyway, I wonder if it does clarify anything... And then there's my new comment attached to the question itself. I'm definately beginning to share in the "academic interest" involved here. (I'm adding this to interesting tags, BTW. ;-))

Answer (score 5):

`print()` uses `sys.stdout.encoding` to determine what the output console can understand and then uses this encoding in the call to `str.encode()`.

[EDIT] If you [look at the source](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/branches/release31-maint/Python/bltinmodule.c), it gets `sys.stdout` and then calls:

```
PyFile_WriteObject(PyTuple_GetItem(args, i), file,
                 Py_PRINT_RAW);
```

I guess the magic is in `Py_PRINT_RAW` but [the source](http://svn.python.org/projects/python/branches/py3k/Objects/fileobject.c) just says:

```
    if (flags & Py_PRINT_RAW) {
    value = PyObject_Str(v);
    }
```

So no magic here. A loop over the arguments with `sys.stdout.write(str(item))` should do the trick.

Comment: +1 for clearing up the important subtlety I entirely missed in my answer.

Comment: While this is probably correct, it does not seem to answer my question. Apparently, print() eventually calls sys.stdout.write() that does some magic because the str.encode(sys.stdout.encoding) fails...

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> import sys
>>> a = '\xAA\xBB\xCC'
>>> print(a)
ª»Ì
```

All `print` is doing here is writing raw **bytes** to `sys.stdout`. The string `a` is a string of bytes, not Unicode characters.

> Why am I asking this? I am sick and tired of encode() errors and realized that since print can do it (at least in the interactive shell). I know that the MUST BE A WAY to magically do the encoding PROPERLY, by digging the info what encoding to use from somewhere...

Alas no, `print` is doing nothing at all magical here. You hand it some bytes, it dumps the bytes to stdout.

To use `.encode()` and `.decode()` properly, you need to understand the difference between bytes and characters, and I'm afraid you do have to figure out the correct encoding to use.

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys

source_file_encoding = 'latin-1' # if there is no -*- coding: ... -*- line

a = '\xaa\xbb\xcc' # raw bytes that represent string in source_file_encoding

# print bytes, my terminal tries to interpret it as 'utf-8'
sys.stdout.write(a+'\n') 
# -> ��

ua = a.decode(source_file_encoding)
sys.stdout.write(ua.encode(sys.stdout.encoding)+'\n')
# -> ª»Ì
```

See [Defining Python Source Code Encodings](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/)