# Assign one dictionary value to another dictionary value in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have one question about assigning one dictionary value to another dictionary value in python, the value contains some Chinese characters

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 
import string
a = {}
a['1'] = '大' # chinese character
b = {}
b['1'] = a['1']
print a['1']
print a
print b
```

And the printout is

```
大
{'1': '\xe5\xa4\xa7'}
{'1': '\xe5\xa4\xa7'}
```

Why there is a difference between `a` and `a['1']`? How to make `print a` be `{'1': '大'}`?

Comment: You created a UTF-8 byte string, which means that any `repr()` output will be shown using escape sequences for non-ASCII bytes. See the duplicate where this is explained in more detail. Don't print out a whole dictionary, print out individual string values.

Comment: I thikn it would be useful to explain what `print` [actually does](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979234/what-does-python-print-function-actually-do)

Answer (score 1):

> Why there is a difference between a and a['1']?

The first (`a`) is your character wrapped in a dictionary. When you print a dictionary, Python will print the raw bytes of the character (`\xe5\xa4\xa7`) which is it's UTF-8 encoding. When you print the string directly using `print a[1]`, then Python will decode these 3 bytes into their respective character.

> How to make a['1'] and b['1'] be 大?

They are already the same. Just do

```
print a['1']
print b['1']
```

Add the following class to dump your dictionary as you expect. Note that *this code assumes all your strings are in UTF-8 format*.

```
class MyPrettyPrinter(pprint.PrettyPrinter):
    def format(self, object, context, maxlevels, level):
        if isinstance(object, str):
            return (object.decode('utf8'), True, False)
        return pprint.PrettyPrinter.format(self, object, context, maxlevels, level)

MyPrettyPrinter().pprint(a)  # {1: 大}
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, can I make `print a` be `{'1': '大'}`？

Comment: Sure, check out the updated answer.

Comment: @zhengyu yes, switch to Python 3. On it `print(a)` produces `{'1': '大'}`