# How to handle unknow encoding

Tags: python, python-2.7, encoding

I'm having some issues with a Python script that needs to open files with different encoding.

**I'm usually using this:**

```
with open(path_to_file, 'r') as f:
    first_line = f.readline()
```

And that works great when the file is properly encode.

**But sometimes, it doesn't work, for example [with this file](http://www.cjoint.com/doc/16_09/FInqYhqOOYi_test.Txt), I've got this:**

```
In [22]: with codecs.open(filename, 'r') as f:
    ...:    a = f.readline()
    ...:    print(a)
    ...:    print(repr(a))
    ...:     
��Test for StackOverlow

'\xff\xfeT\x00e\x00s\x00t\x00 \x00f\x00o\x00r\x00 \x00S\x00t\x00a\x00c\x00k\x00O\x00v\x00e\x00r\x00l\x00o\x00w\x00\r\x00\n'
```

**And I would like to search some stuff on those lines. Sadly with that method, I can't:**

```
In [24]: "Test" in a
Out[24]: False
```

**I've found a lot of questions here referring to the same type of issues:**

1. [Unicode (UTF-8) reading and writing to files in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/491921/unicode-utf8-reading-and-writing-to-files-in-python)
2. [UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xa5 in position 0: invalid start byte](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22216076/unicodedecodeerror-utf8-codec-cant-decode-byte-0xa5-in-position-0-invalid-s)
3. https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/187169/how-to-detect-the-encoding-of-a-file
4. [how can i escape '\xff\xfe' to a readable string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1979171/how-can-i-escape-xff-xfe-to-a-readable-string)

But can't manage to decode the file properly with them...

**With codecs.open():**

```
In [17]: with codecs.open(filename, 'r', "utf-8") as f:
    a = f.readline()
    print(a)
   ....:     
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-17-0e72208eaac2> in <module>()
      1 with codecs.open(filename, 'r', "utf-8") as f:
----> 2     a = f.readline()
      3     print(a)
      4 

/usr/lib/python2.7/codecs.pyc in readline(self, size)
    688     def readline(self, size=None):
    689 
--> 690         return self.reader.readline(size)
    691 
    692     def readlines(self, sizehint=None):

/usr/lib/python2.7/codecs.pyc in readline(self, size, keepends)
    543         # If size is given, we call read() only once
    544         while True:
--> 545             data = self.read(readsize, firstline=True)
    546             if data:
    547                 # If we're at a "\r" read one extra character (which might

/usr/lib/python2.7/codecs.pyc in read(self, size, chars, firstline)
    490             data = self.bytebuffer + newdata
    491             try:
--> 492                 newchars, decodedbytes = self.decode(data, self.errors)
    493             except UnicodeDecodeError, exc:
    494                 if firstline:

UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte
```

**with encode('utf-8):**

```
In [18]: with codecs.open(filename, 'r') as f:
    a = f.readline()
    print(a)
   ....:     a.encode('utf-8')
   ....:     print(a)
   ....:     
��Test for StackOverlow

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
UnicodeDecodeError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-7facc05b9cb1> in <module>()
      2     a = f.readline()
      3     print(a)
----> 4     a.encode('utf-8')
      5     print(a)
      6 

UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

**I've found a way to change file encoding automatically with Vim:**

```
system("vim '+set fileencoding=utf-8' '+wq' %s" % path_to_file)
```

But I would like to do this without using Vim...

Any help will be appreciate.

Comment: there are some ways to try and autodetect encoding... see https://pypi.python.org/pypi/chardet ... but its risky ... chances are if its not "utf8" then its "latin1"

Comment: No, this is definitely UTF-16 little-endian. A UTF-8 BOM would be \xEF\xBB\xBF. This file's BOM and conspicuous pattern of null bytes indicates UTF-16 little-endian.

Comment: @JoranBeasley, thanks for your help, but I'm getting `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte` with `a.decode("utf-8-sig")`

Comment: yeah i was wrong ... see @user2357112's comment

Comment: @user2357112 with both `a.decode("utf-16-le")` and `a.decode("utf-16")` I'm getting: `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf16' codec can't decode byte 0x0a in position 46: truncated data`

Comment: @XavierC.: Yeah, it looks like this file got corrupted somehow. It's missing a trailing null byte.

Comment: @user2357112 but then how every text editor I've tried always succeed to open it?

Comment: @XavierC.: Most likely, the text editor is doing its best to show you something reasonable instead of just spitting out an error message.

Comment: Oh, wait, you tried to `decode` the line instead of specifying a codec in `codecs.open`. That's why it's complaining about truncated data. You need to specify the codec when you open the file.

Comment: @user2357112 exact... with `with codecs.open(filename2, 'r', 'utf-16-le') as f:` it's perfect!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

it looks like this is utf-16-le (utf-16 little endian ...) but you are missing a final `\x00`

```
>>> s = '\xff\xfeT\x00e\x00s\x00t\x00 \x00f\x00o\x00r\x00 \x00S\x00t\x00a\x00c\x
00k\x00O\x00v\x00e\x00r\x00l\x00o\x00w\x00\r\x00\n'
>>> s.decode('utf-16-le') # creates error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Python26\lib\encodings\utf_16_le.py", line 16, in decode
    return codecs.utf_16_le_decode(input, errors, True)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf16' codec can't decode byte 0x0a in position 46: truncat
ed data
>>> (s+"\x00").decode("utf-16-le") # TADA!!!!
u'\ufeffTest for StackOverlow\r\n'
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks! In fact the missing `\x00` was next line and so on.

Answer (score 5):

It looks like you need to detect the encoding in the input file. The `chardet` library mentioned in the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436220/python-is-there-a-way-to-determine-the-encoding-of-text-file) might help (though note the proviso that complete encoding detection is not possible).

Then you can write the file out in a known encoding, perhaps. When dealing with Unicode remember that it MUST be encoded into a suitable bytestream before being communicated outside the process. Decode on input, then encode on output.

Comment: actually adressing the OP's stated question +1

Comment: @holdenweb, I agree with JoranBeasley when he says that you answer to my real question, how to find the encoding, but as he solves my issue with the input file example, I will accept his answer. Eventually, thanks for your help.

Comment: Sure, but JoranBeasley gave you the UTF-16 you need for your specific data set.